# Htm.DropdownFor validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I'm working on a MVC4 project and I'm having some strange behavior the jQuery validation is checking the text in the dropdown instead of the value:

```
    // field in model
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string StateCode { get; set; }

    // source of states  -> List.States
    Dictionary<string, string> states = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      states.Add("AK", "Alaska");
      states.Add("AZ", "Arizona");
      // etc.
      states.Add("WI", "Wisconsin");
      states.Add("WY", "Wyoming");
    }

    // in the controller
    ViewBag.States = new SelectList(Lists.States(), "Key", "Value", Lists.States["AK"]);

    <!-- in the view -->
    <li>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StateCode)
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateCode, (SelectList)ViewBag.States, "Alaska")
    </li>
```

and here is the error message I'm getting:
•The State must be 2 characters long.

Comment: Can you temporarily remove validation and check to see what the value being posted back actually is?

Comment: It really makes no sense that you have a length rule on a drop-down since the user has no control over any of that.  What exactly are you trying to do here?  And since we're talking about JavaScript code, show the _rendered_ HTML code since that's all JavaScript can see.

Comment: it is a two char string. example "LA".

Comment: HTML: <select data-val="true" data-val-length="The State must be 2 characters long." data-val-length-max="2" data-val-length-min="2" data-val-required="The State field is required." id="StateCode" name="StateCode"><option value="">Alaska</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
Since my DB field only holds 2 chars. I don't see why not to use the constraint.  I don't like going around problems and I am would like to find out what is causing the behavior. 
Thnx
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>

Comment: Does this occur if you select a different option to the default?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417643/mvc-dropdownlistfor-and-stringlength-attribute-not-playing-well-together)

Comment: If you want to protect your database, you would put the 2-character rule in your _server-side_ validation.  Again, this kind of thing makes absolutely no sense on the _client-side_ validation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because jquery is checking the number of items selected.

```
maxlength: function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || this.getLength($.trim(value), element) <= param;
}

getLength: function(value, element) {
    switch( element.nodeName.toLowerCase() ) {
        case 'select':
            return $("option:selected", element).length;
        case 'input':
            if( this.checkable( element) )
                return this.findByName(element.name).filter(':checked').length;
    }
    return value.length;
}
```

Comment: Yes, even if I don't use a default at all.